# AWS NLB routing from separate CIDR block thru DirectConnect

Tags: amazon-web-services, routing, nlb

In my VPC I have 2 CIDR blocks, one can only have a very limited number of IPs, so a very small CIDR block that also has routing rules to be able to talk through a DX to a CORP network.  If I were to create another, larger, CIDR block of different IPs, could I route traffic through the smaller subnet and to servers on the CORP network over the DX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this question is No - kinda of.  You would need to update the IPs advertised [BGP] to the DX and assuming that CIDR isn't already taken by another route it could work.  But it will not work by just creating the new CIDR in the VPC.